# What can I do to make 'id' = id in this class-based view in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import Producto


def general_view(request):
    context = {
        'articulos': Producto.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/general_view.html', context)


class DetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Producto
    template_name = 'shop/specific_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['determinado'] = Producto.objects.get(pk=*¿?*)
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import DetailedView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.general_view, name='general-view'),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailedView.as_view(), name='specific-article'),
]
```

As you see, the problem occurs because I don't know how to call the id or pk in the detailed_view in views.py, I'm guessing you maybe have to do a dictionary but I don't know where to do it nor how. It works if I set the id to 1, but obviously what this does is that is shows in every url with a different id the same article.

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* need to do that yourself. The idea is that the `DetailView` has the boilerplate code, to automatically filter on the primary key. You can simply set the [**`.context_object_name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.context_object_name) to `'determinado'`:

```
class DetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Producto
    template_name = 'shop/specific_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'determinado'

    # no override of get_context_data
```